# Recyclerview items removes data when scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make add and remove cart page using `RecyclerView`. When i add or remove count on the `RecyclerView` items then scroll `RecyclerView` to bottom and then when i move up my previously selected data has been cleared. 
Help me for this .

Comment: Can you please provide a little code so we can help you ?

Comment: My code is simple code recyclerview with adapter. Items are displayed correctly. Problem occures when i scroll.

Comment: How come this get +1 ? Its utterly lacking a [mcve].